# Flutter and device specific functionality

Tags: flutter

I'm very new to flutter but have been reading through a lot of documentation. I can't seem to understand this part of it though.

I'm pretty sure React Native wraps some of the device APIs (like vibration for example) in a device-agnostic way so you can access them generically. Additional APIs would need plugins, and you would use conditional statements and files to execute on different platforms.

**That's React Native, on flutter how does this work?**

1. Is everything literally a plugin for this?
2. And, I can't find any canonical examples of executing code for
   android and not for iOS for example.

ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Is everything literally a plugin for this?

Yes pretty much. However many of the basic plugins you are talking about are maintained by the flutter team themselves. See [this](https://pub.dev/publishers/flutter.dev/packages) for a list of such packages.

I don't know the reason they are not included in the main SDK for sure but I would say it's for easier maintainability.

#### 2. Canonical examples of executing code for android and not for iOS for example.

This question has 2 subcategories:

- Executing different dart code depending on the current platform
- Calling native code from dart to access platform specific functionalities.

**Executing different dart code depending on the current platform**

This is the easiest of the two, simple check the value of `Platform.is...`:

```dart
main() {
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    runApp(MyCupertinoApp())
  } else {
    runApp(MyAndroidApp())
  }
}
```

You can use this anywhere, from changing the entire app to the color of a button.

**Calling native code from dart to access platform specific functionalities**

This uses a mechanism called `Platform channels`. This is how the packages like [camera](https://pub.dev/publishers/flutter.dev/packages) are build for example (they are open source so you can check their code on github directly).

Platform channel is a bigger topic than I can cover here but you can [check this great tutorial by the flutter team](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) or simply search `Platform Channel flutter` on google.

Comment: If I understand, everywhere you use a plug-in like that you have to do a conditional check right? Are there cross platform plugins?

Comment: Not at all! Must of the plugins are cross platform, on pub.dev you can see bellow there name which platform are supported. For example for the `camera` package you can see `Flutter | Android iOS web` meaning that the desktop OS are not supported but the other are. You sometimes have platform specific parameters (which does not have equivalent in the other platform) -in which case the naming of the parameter should reflect this and should be ignored without failure on other OS. Something else that you can encounter (`camera` is a good example) are platform specific settings that you have to

Comment: change (often in `Info.plist` or `build.gradle`). Those are rare but if they exist they should be specified in the README on pub.dev (you can check the `camera` package for an example)